# Server Error in '/' Application. in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC application Host the IIS Server. It's showing folders I clicked views folder show the below error.

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /PMS/Views/
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Comment: 1) you can google what a 404 error means, 2) that's not how you access a view in an MVC application

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's relevant to yourself but I only get this error when I try to start the application on a page which requires a value to start.

For example you have a garage page that requires a garageId to set values/ show details. Because there is no value being passed to the page, that page cannot be found.

Comment: Hi JamesS, Thanks.. same publish folder is working some other systems. Ex: my laptop working fine.But my desktop and office system are not working..